# Raspi 3 PIR sensor - Python script - invalid syntax

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, magic-mirror

actually I´m working at a "Magic Mirror" and now I got a problem with the python script wich should turning my monitor on/off.

[I copied the python script from this site](https://helentronica.wordpress.com/2016/01/11/magic-mirror-with-motion-detector/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
import RPi.GPIO as io
import subprocess

io.setmode(io.BCM)
SHUTOFF_DELAY = 60  # seconds
PIR_PIN = 7         # Pin 26 on the board

def main():
io.setup(PIR_PIN, io.IN)
turned_off = False
last_motion_time = time.time()

while True:
    if io.input(PIR_PIN):
        last_motion_time = time.time()
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if turned_off:
            turned_off = False
            turn_on()
    else:
        if not turned_off and time.time() &amp;gt; (last_motion_time + SHUTOFF_DELAY):
            turned_off = True
            turn_off()
    time.sleep(.1)

def turn_on():
subprocess.call(&amp;quot;sh /home/pi/Documents/PIR/monitor_on.sh&amp;quot;, shell=True)

def turn_off():
subprocess.call(&amp;quot;sh /home/pi/Documents/PIR/monitor_off.sh&amp;quot;, shell=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    io.cleanup()
```

I tried to run the script, but python tell me there is a syntax error at line 25, it points exactly at the semicolon after **&amp** and before **gt**

I didn't worked with python until now, therefore I don't know anything about the syntax of python.

I would appreciate it very much if you guys will take a minute to help me solving my problem.

**I got the python version 2.7.9**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the exact copy of the original Python file. You copied some HTML markup while copying the file.

Replace `&amp;gt;` with `>`.

```
    if not turned_off and time.time() > (last_motion_time + SHUTOFF_DELAY):
        turned_off = True
        turn_off()
```

You also have indentation issues and other HTML stuff you should get rid of:

```
def main():
    io.setup(PIR_PIN, io.IN)
    turned_off = False
    last_motion_time = time.time()
```

and

```
def turn_on():
    subprocess.call("sh /home/pi/Documents/PIR/monitor_on.sh", shell=True)

def turn_off():
    subprocess.call("sh /home/pi/Documents/PIR/monitor_off.sh", shell=True)
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much!! This works like a charm xD ... I had this trouble before in the past, but I did't remember.